# WPF Style using ControlTemplate not loading correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Can anyone help me with a problem please, I am creating a custom window and have created my Generic.xaml which contains the following reference to the new window theme

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Cleo.Windows.Ui.Controls.AeroWindow;component/Themes/AdministrationWindow.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And in the AdministrationWindow.xml file I added the following:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="AdministrationWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type aeroWindow:AdministrationWindow}">
    <Grid Background="Red">
        <ContentPresenter />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type aeroWindow:AdministrationWindow}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource AdministrationWindowStyle}" />
</Style>
```

So from the above I should get a window with a Red background, right? Well I don't, when I run the application I get a window with a title bar and a black client area.

If i try the following then i do get the correct result

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type aeroWindow:AdministrationWindow}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type aeroWindow:AdministrationWindow}">
                <Grid Background="Red">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have seen the first approach used before on many occasions but I cannot understand why I cannot get the desired result using this approach, can anyone shed any light please?

Comment: Is AdministrationWindow.xaml ResourceDictionary?

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but couldn't you just use a `StaticResource` instead of a `DynamicResource`?